# Are men allowed to compete in underwear or only shorts in Olympics marathon?

Tags: rules, olympics

In Olympics marathon race, are men allowed to run by wearing only underwear, or underwear can only be worn by women while racing?

Comment: I don't think women are allowed to run wearing only underwear. Where did you get that info?